# Access Exchange 2003 mailbox from Terminal

Tags: command-line, email, mail, ms-exchange

How do I check an Exchange mailbox for new mail from the command line?

I'm at a complete loss here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need fetchmail or davmail to sync with access the exchange server from terminal otherwise thunderbird has the ability to do that.

See here for instruction ablut thunderbird:
http://downloadsquad.switched.com/2007/03/30/howto-thunderbird-and-ms-exchange-server/

Comment: Thanks!! I used DavMail, in combination with Mutt. Perfect!

Comment: This also works for MS 2007 as well